# XNA Reach profile with VMWare - Vertex Buffers not working?

Tags: c#, xna, directx

Running XNA app, using Reach profile, in VMWare Fusion host OS Mac OSX, VM is Windows XP SP 3 (my dual-boot OS).  Running on MacBook Pro w/NVidia 320M graphics card

When I am booted in to XP natively, my code works.  The code is drawing cubes that are set up using vertex buffers

When another friend runs this same code on Windows 7, it also works for him just fine

When I am running my code in the VM, it doesn't work.  I have billboarding sprites running in a shader program and this part displays fine.  I get no crashing or errors, the geometry just doesn't appear.  I tried Debug and Release.  This is very basic operation so I'm thinking VMWare isn't the problem, but it's my code....

Also, if I switch my DrawIndexedPrimitives to DrawUserIndexPrimitives (using memory objects instead of vertex buffers) everything works fine...   An acceptable solution would be to know how I can query the hardware to figure out if this will work or not work so that my code can conditionally use either memory objects or vertex buffers.

My init code:

```
  var vertexArray = verts.ToArray();
  var indexArray = indices.ToArray();

  indexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(Int16), indexArray.Length, BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
  indexBuffer.SetData(indexArray);

  vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(GraphicsDevice, typeof(VertexPositionColor), vertexArray.Length,
    BufferUsage.WriteOnly);
  vertexBuffer.SetData(vertexArray);
```

My Draw code:

```
 // problem isn't here, tried no cull
  GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullClockwise;
  GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
  GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = new DepthStencilState() { DepthBufferEnable = true };
// Update View and Projection
  TileEffect.View = ((Game1)Game).Camera.View;
  TileEffect.Projection = ((Game1)Game).Camera.Projection;

  TileEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

  GraphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);
  GraphicsDevice.Indices = indexBuffer;

  GraphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, indices.Count, 0, indices.Count / 3);
```

For LoadContent:

```
 TileEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice)
  {
    World = Matrix.Identity,
    View = ((Game1)Game).Camera.View,
    Projection = ((Game1)Game).Camera.Projection,
    VertexColorEnabled = true
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching from indicies resolved the issue although I still don't know why it would..

Answer (score 0):

you have to realize that running this in a VM hosted on MAC is not a fully supported scenario. I suppose there might be some quirk with some state that you have to set in order for it to work with vmware, but it's not immediately apparent to me ... you're right, it is a fairly basic operation :-/

Comment: Well, it sort of is a supported scenario.. I realize it adds a layer of complexity/source of problems, but VMWare isn't no-name software and it officially supports DX 9.0c and shader model 3 and can play commercial 3d games and lots of other things.  That's why I start to think it's me

Comment: Just a thought... Did you consider using Parallels or VirtualBox?

Comment: Right, but that support would then come from VMWare and their support channels :-)